# Unknown Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am using the following code to insert data from an access database, into a MySQL Database using PHP, and struggling.

```
$id = $keys['id'];
$ug = $values['usertype'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO [" & public_user_usergroup_map & "] (user_id, group_id) values ($id, $ug)"; 
CustomQuery($sql);
```

any ideas please

Comment: try changing [" & public_user_usergroup_map & "] to [" . public_user_usergroup_map . "]

Comment: mysql doesn't use `[]` for escaping field/table names. and `&` is a bitwise AND operation. not string concatentation. This is basically not PHP. You're trying to write visual basic or something.

Comment: Tried that, it then says Description: Could not find output table 'public_user_usergroup_map'.

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO ". $public_user_usergroup_map . " (user_id, group_id) values ($id, $ug)";` If the public_user_usergroup_map is a variable or a constant. If not, php just use it as it is.

Comment: public_user_usergroup_map is the table name

Comment: It seems like you literally used the brackets from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]`

Comment: Then just use as a name, `$sql = "INSERT INTO public_user_usergroup_map (user_id, group_id) values ($id, $ug)";`

Comment: Plus, where is your `CustomQuery()` function?

Comment: Yes, I tried the $sql = "INSERT INTO public_user_usergroup_map (user_id, group_id) values ($id, $ug)"; as my first attempt and it didnt like it at all, and customerQuery is there

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$id = $keys['id'];
$ug = $values['usertype'];
$table_name = "table_a";


$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . " (user_id, group_id) VALUES ('$id', '$ug')"; 
CustomQuery($sql);
```

Comment: Thats gotten it closer, now I get Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I erroneously had single quotes around the table name. Try this one instead.

Comment: ok, tried that and now get Description: Could not find output table 'public_user_usergroup_map'., but i know that it exists

Comment: Have you selected the database first with mysql_select_db($databaseName); ?

Comment: No how would i do that?  as an extra line before, or as part of the $tablename ?

Comment: Can you modify your question to include anything that comes before this point in the script? The problem may be outside of what you've posted above. Also, where is CustomQuery defined? Post that function too.

Comment: Ok I have added this to now include and I am getting Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: There are no substr()'s here, so it sounds like your problem is outside of this scope. It may be best to open up a new question at this point for your other problem.

Answer (score 0):

good one

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '. $table_name .' (user_id, group_id) VALUES ('.$id.', '.$ug.')";
```

bad one

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (user_id, group_id) VALUES ($id, $ug)";
```